# Automate Live App Deployment

Tags: release, liveapps, automated-process

I am looking if we can package and deploy/publish the [live app](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liveapps) through any bash or nodejs scripts. Could someone confirm if thats possible? and if Yes, how?

Thanks,
Vally

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, although does require having credentials configured - this guide outlines what a normal release cycle might look like: https://quip.com/dev/liveapps/1.x.x/guide/manage-release-cycles

The command you're looking for is probably `quip-cli publish`, which is documented here: https://github.com/quip/quip-apps/tree/next/packages/quip-cli#qla-publish

The short answer is that before deploying, you'd need to authenticate the command line using `quip-cli login` - this will create a `.quiprc` file with an access token in it in your `$HOME` directory. In theory you could manually generate this file in a CI environment using a token that you've generated in a different environment if you'd like to automate publishing.

One caveat is that Live Apps require that the manifest version is bumped every time you publish - you can do this easily by running `quip-cli bump` in the project directory. You can also increment the user-facing version number at the same time by using `quip-cli bump [increment]` as per https://github.com/quip/quip-apps/tree/next/packages/quip-cli#qla-bump-increment

Comment: Thanks Jesse. This is working :)